IntelliJ Java SQLException (table not found) even if table is there
I am studying java and have started learning about database implementation. I have decided to use SQLite and have already downloaded the .jav file, placed it in the classpath and used it in command prompt to create a database with two tables: dept and students.
When I try to run some simple code in java I always get an SQLException saying the students table does not exist despite it defiitely being there. I have checked the path and the tables many times but just can't see the issue. If I don't fix this I will not be able to continue learning JDBC so it is very important. Here is the code:
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C://sqlite//univ");

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from students");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.print(rs.getInt("rollno") + " ");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("name") + " ");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("city") + " ");
                System.out.print(rs.getInt("deptno") + " ");
            }
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

This is the Error:
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: students)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1179)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1190)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:1150)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:135)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:264)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.lambda$executeQuery$1(JDBC3Statement.java:87)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.withConnectionTimeout(JDBC3Statement.java:458)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeQuery(JDBC3Statement.java:85)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Are you sure that you're getting a connection to the same database (file) that you created via command-line tools?  SQLite would probably allow you to create a connection to a file that does not already exist, because it's prepared to create that file.

This was spot on, I came to the same conclusion when I saw the two files in the folder but I remember there was only one, thank you for your comment.

So the issue was actually in the filepath, it specifies "univ" instead of "univ.db". It confused me because despite the blunder, the connection was still being established so I was looking for the problem elsewhere. When creating the database it created univ and univ.db, whatever univ is, it doesn't have the tables I created.
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/univ.db");

